# Rails REST API design question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, rest

I am designing a REST api for one of my applications & considering using RoR for the same and had a few questions that I was wondering if Rails can support before I can decide on RoR -

1) does rails support setting HTTP response code status. So I want something like this

```
if customer_save_fail
 response.status_code = 500
end
```

2) in rails is there a way to execute straight up SQL statement, i want this for complex queries & dont want to use ActiveRecord. I am guessing I can use DBI gem for this? Is there any other way? that integrates with Rails. Also I need a way to convert the resultsets returned by straight queries into JSON, something like to_json. Can I achieve something like this with RoR out of the box?

Thanks all for your inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, Rails has mappings for the HTTP status codes which you can call from your controller actions with [head](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000466) (as one option). See [here](http://www.codyfauser.com/2008/7/4/rails-http-status-code-to-symbol-mapping) for the list.

2) If you want to stay in or close to SQL in your application then you have [options](http://gilesbowkett.blogspot.com/2007/02/direct-sql-access-from-within-rails.html) within AR or you could use another ORM like [Sequel](http://github.com/pusewicz/rails_sequel/). Examples of the later approach [here](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/sql_rdoc.html).

UPDATE: Expanding on detail above

1) You can respond with a body and a status in your controller action. For example.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render :json => @some_object.to_json, :status => :not_implemented }
end
```

2) The `execute` interface is pretty low-level and returns an result object which is an instance of your particular database adapter's result. For example MySQL returns a [MySQL::Result](http://www.tmtm.org/en/mysql/ruby/). If you need to process the results in a more abstracted manner you might like to take a look at the [wrappers here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html)

Comment: And I should have added that there are to-JSON conversion options too, the easiest-to-use of which come from leveraging the ORM facilities in the framework, something you may not be planning to do by the looks of it

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. So is head the only option, coz head = Return a response that has no content (merely headers). I want a way to send specific status code with some content. For example send a json error object with status code 500.

Model.connection.execute looks perfect, but whats does it return, hash??

Comment: Thanks a lot, you have been of great help. Model.connection.select("some select") is exactly what I am looking for my complex queries. It - "Returns an array of record hashes with the column names as keys and column values as values" ...meaning I can just call a to_json on that array object and all the magic is done :) thanks much!!

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, you can things like `render :text => "response", :status => 500`. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000464
2) Yes, you can do Model.find_by_sql("sql query"). http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001781